# Dynamically populate second Combobox with variable from first ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am stuck with a problem with ComboBox in Excel VBA. Any help is highly appreciated.
This is what I am trying to do:

- In a UserForm, user chooses an input from a first ComboBox named "ComboBox_groesse" (regular ComboBox with a fixed RowSource. Inputs are numbers)
- When the DropButton of a second ComboBox named "ComboBox_config_1" is clicked, this ComboBox will be populate with the values from a NamedRange "KonfiRange_1_1" that is equal to the value of the chosen ComboBox_groesse.value
- the NamedRange is in a table that has 2 columns. The first column is the NamedRange with numbers, the second with text.
- I would like the correspondent text to be appeared in the second ComboBox together with the values that are equal to ComboBox_groesse.value

I have written the codes below but I am getting a blank ComboBox_config_1. Could any one please help? Thanks in advance!

```
 Private Sub ComboBox_config_1_DropButtonClick()

    Dim teil As Range

    For Each teil In Tabelle1.Range("KonfiRange_1_1")

    If teil.Value = ComboBox_groesse.Value Then

        With Me.ComboBox_config_1

        .AddItem teil.Value

        End With

    End If
    Next teil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this operation in the ComboBox_groesse_Change event, like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_groesse_Change()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strList As String

    Me.ComboBox_config_1.Clear
    If Me.ComboBox_groesse.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub 'Nothing selected

    With Range("KonfiRange_1_1")
        Set rngFound = .Find(Me.ComboBox_groesse.Text, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                strList = strList & "|" & rngFound.Offset(, 1).Text
                Set rngFound = .Find(Me.ComboBox_groesse.Text, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    End With

    If Len(strList) > 0 Then Me.ComboBox_config_1.List = Split(Mid(strList, 2), "|")

    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```